# Duplicate symbole issue in gDrive SDK integration in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-drive-api, cocoapods

I am trying to integrate Google Drive API in my App. Everything went on but when I tried to compile app, it gave following errors. I also have pods installed into my workspace:

I am posting part of error:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.queries* in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.additionalHTTPHeaders* in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.urlQueryParameters* in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.requestIDMap* in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTLBatchQuery.skipAuthorization* in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLBatchQuery in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTLBatchQuery.o)
> ```
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTLBatchQuery.o)
>
> duplicate symbol
>   _OBJC_IVAR_$*GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.didViewAppear* in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain in:
>
> ```
> /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
>
> /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
> ```
>
> duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain in:
>   /Users/am/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AMCAT-gpiriurdkrrgvmdhpqxzqnncgljq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libGTLTouchStaticLib.a(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)
>   /Users/amit/ios/GoogleOpenSource.framework/GoogleOpenSource(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.o)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have added library 2 times one time manually and second time through pods. Find the library in the pods folder in pod project. And also see in your xcode project if its there than delete one of them. I would recommend try to delete your library which you added manually. Pods handle lots of things so don't delete it.

Comment: Nopes, Thats not the case. Before adding gdrive, everything was working fine.